# Brightness not changing Dell 15r SE and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dell, brightness, function-keys

With my current laptop I can't change my brightness anymore

I tried xbacklight -set 50 (nothing happened)

and also changed this line

> grub_cmdline_linux_default= "quiet splash"

to

> grub_cmdline_linux_default= "quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

and updated the grub but still it didn't solve the problem.
Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .bashrc:

```
alias screen='xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness $1'
```

Than you can enter

```
screen 0.9
```

And the brightness changes.